# Android : E/InputDispatcher: Window handle drag has no registered input channel

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

In my  app,  I am dragging a customView on the screen and based on the  location of the finger,  I update certain arrangement of other views. I keep getting this error  in  my Logcat. Few seconds after the drag  is in progress, the parent view gets all dark and doesn't get updated. I  also keep seeing this error:

```
 E/InputDispatcher: Window handle drag has no registered input channel
```

But the  app does respond - not totally irresponsive.  Any ideas on how to solve it?
sorry, I am not able to share code as it is part of huge module and it is hard to make  it small to show it here.

Comment: did you solve the issue? facing the same issue.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not share code, it is hard to give an answer that fits your use case.
I was hiding the soft keyboard programmicaly and got the same error:

```
2022-03-19 15:57:13.674 2069-3576/system_process E/InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{5f5b041 u0 app.ui.activities.LoginActivity} has no registered input channel
```

I solved it by changing the `InputMethodManager` "." `hideSoftInputFromWindow` method first "windowToken" argument 
FROM: `view.getWindowToken()` or `view.windowToken` 
TO: `view.applicationWindowToken` which removed the logcat error.

I was using the emulator.